# Better way to add alternative using update-alternatives?

Tags: command-line, alternatives

I've looked up the manual of `update-alternatives` several times but I can't find out how to show the current link pointing to a specific alternative, and that information is needed when adding a new alternative.

From the `update-alternatives` manual:

```
--install <link> <name> <path> <priority>
```

Let's say I want to add a new version of Java Runtime Edition, but I don't know the current symlink that links to the alternative (`<link>` parameter). What I currently do is:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /tmp/randomStuff java /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/bin/java 0
```

That command will output:

```
update-alternatives: renaming java link from /usr/local/bin/java to /tmp/randomStuff.
```

Reading the output I find out the old link that was pointing to the alternative, so I can finally run my command again with the right `<link>` parameter, changing `/tmp/randomStuff` to `/usr/local/bin/java`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/local/bin/java java /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_25/bin/java 0
```

That works fine, but as you see, running the command with `/tmp/randomStuff` as the `<link>` parameter is very awkward.

So, here comes the questions: (1) Are there any `update-alternative` arguments that can output the current link that is pointing to a specific alternative, or (2) is there a way to install a new alternative without having to provide a new  parameter, simply keeping the current `<link>`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer your first question I'd like to hint you to [`--query`](http://man.cx/update-alternatives):

```
   --query name
          Display information about the link group like --display does, but in a machine parseable way (see section QUERY FORMAT below).
```

Armed with this you will get the link source, e.g. in my case for java:

```
usr@srv % update-alternatives --query java
Name: java
Link: /usr/bin/java
[...]
```

So, you see my chain goes like `/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java -> ...`.

Unfortunately, I don't have an answer to your second question. I've been searching for a solution for this some time ago, but it seems that there is no simple workaround, yet. What you could do is writing some hack to parse the output of the `--query` call, maybe like this:

```
update-alternatives --query java | /bin/grep Link | cut -f 2 -d " "
```

which you could then use as input for the `--install` call. But since this is quite messy in my opinion I won't recommend it. Instead you might want to have a look at [`galternatives`](http://binfalse.de/2012/04/galternatives/), a front-end to the alternatives system. Even if I don't like to use graphical stuff for such basic jobs it is quite convenient and I ended up using this tool instead of the command line tools.

**EDIT**

I've been curious how `update-alternatives` knows what's the command symlink and took a short look into the sources. Of course the alternatives system has to store the config for each group and it turns out that it's called *administrative directory* and written on the man page ;-)

You'll find this information in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` (by default). The second line in each of these files defines the *master link* you're looking for. You may extract it like this:

```
usr@srv $ sed -ne 2p /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java
/usr/bin/java
```

However, this is just a workaround for those having an older version of `update-alternatives`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the version of update-alternatives that I'm running (1.16.1.2) does not show link information using neither --query or --display. What version are you using?

`sudo update-alternatives --query java
Link: java
Status: auto
Best: /usr/local/java/jre1.6.0_45/bin/java
Value: /usr/local/java/jre1.6.0_45/bin/java
Alternative: /usr/local/java/jre1.6.0_45/bin/java
Priority: 0`

Comment: I've `1.16.10` installed. Can't you update your version?

Comment: You are the man! Both solutions are excellent!

Comment: That's the way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Simpleton question here:  Isn't the `<link>` always going to be the same one retrieved by a simple `which [program]` since that is the link that the system uses to call a program by command-line?

For instance, tracing back the links for pycharm I get:

```
user@computer:~$ which pycharm
/usr/bin/pycharm
user@computer:~$ ll /usr/bin/pycharm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Mar 12  2015 /usr/bin/pycharm -> /etc/alternatives/pycharm*
user@computer:~$ ll /etc/alternatives/pycharm 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Mar 12  2015 /etc/alternatives/pycharm -> /opt/pycharm-community-4.0.5/bin/pycharm.sh*
```

And I can then use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pycharm pycharm /opt/pycharm-community-4.5.0/bin/pycharm.sh 0
```

For my new pycharm install.

Then maybe you could construct a script to use the output of `which`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but there are times when that will not be helpful. I use `update-alternatives` to also keep track of java and flash plugins for firefox, and I always forget the path "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins" where I should put those plugins. I can't find out that path using `which` or `whereis`or any command that comes to my mind, whereas the answer from @binfalse correctly returns that path on my machine when I run `update-alternatives --query java-plugin`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to resupply all the existing alternatives when using --install. See the example at https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives. Here I'm adding /usr/local/bin/alacritty as an alternative for x-terminal-emulator, and selecting it:

```
[schwarzgerat](0) $ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emualtor x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/alacritty 10
update-alternatives: renaming x-terminal-emulator link from /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator to /usr/bin/x-terminal-emualtor
[schwarzgerat](0) $ sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
There are 16 choices for the alternative x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emualtor).

  Selection    Path                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/terminator               50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/kitty                    20        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/koi8rxterm               20        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/konsole                  40        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/lxterm                   30        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/mlterm                   20        manual mode
  7            /usr/bin/pangoterm                15        manual mode
  8            /usr/bin/st                       15        manual mode
  9            /usr/bin/terminator               50        manual mode
  10           /usr/bin/terminology              40        manual mode
  11           /usr/bin/terminus                 20        manual mode
  12           /usr/bin/urxvt                    20        manual mode
  13           /usr/bin/uxterm                   20        manual mode
  14           /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper   40        manual mode
  15           /usr/bin/xterm                    20        manual mode
  16           /usr/local/bin/alacritty          10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 16
update-alternatives: using /usr/local/bin/alacritty to provide /usr/bin/x-terminal-emualtor (x-terminal-emulator) in manual mode
[schwarzgerat](0) $
```