# Why use the alternatives command?

Tags: docker, alternatives

I'm following instructions from [this site](https://springframework.guru/running-spring-boot-in-a-docker-container) about building a spring-boot docker container.  They are using CentOS.

In their dockerfile, they call the alternative command several times.  I would like to understand the purpose of these statements.

note: run is a docker command.  I am interested in the alternative command passed to run

```
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/java jar /usr/java/latest/bin/java 200000
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/latest/bin/javaws 200000
RUN alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/java/latest/bin/javac 200000
```

From what I can tell they are modifying symbolic links.  Is that correct and, more importantly, why?

Thnx

Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have a need to keep multiple versions of an executable (like java) on your system.  Perhaps most of your system will work with Java 8, but one application needs Java 7.

The [alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives) program lets you switch from one version to another, quickly.

EDIT: For other reasons you may want to do this, see [What is the difference between JAVA_HOME and update-alternatives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123412/158322) and [Better way to add alternative using update-alternatives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/81992/158322)

From [man alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives):

> It is possible for several programs fulfilling the same or similar
> functions to be installed on a single system at the same time. For
> example, many systems have several text editors installed at once.
> This gives choice to the users of a system, allowing each to use a
> different editor, if desired, but makes it difficult for a program to
> make a good choice of editor to invoke if the user has not specified a
> particular preference.
>
> The **alternatives** system aims to solve this problem. A generic name in
> the filesystem is shared by all files providing interchangeable
> functionality. The alternatives system and the system administrator
> together determine which actual file is referenced by this generic
> name.

---

Comment: So that makes sense if I was running the OS interactively, I guess.  Why would that matter in a situation where the OS is running a docker file and only function is to run a spring-boot app?

Comment: The deployment in question has no way to notice that you have pinky-promised to only ever use that host for that singular purpose.